# Date Chart in aChartEngine

Tags: java, android, eclipse, achartengine

I have edited my question...

Here is the code I am using, I am adding weight of an animal with time.

```
    else if (str.equals("Weight"))
    {
        mDbHelper.open();
        wtArray = mDbHelper.getWeight();
        mDbHelper.close();

       TimeSeries diaSeries = new TimeSeries("Weight");

        for ( int i =0; i <wtArray.size(); i++)
        {
           Weight wt = wtArray.get(i);
           diaSeries.add(wt.date, wt.weight);
        }


        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(diaSeries);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mrenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

        graphLayout.addView(ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset, mrenderer, "MM/dd/yyyy"));
    }
```

It never shows any value on x axis, i-e time. I am using LinearLayout. Kindly tell me what is wrong. Also no Graph line is showing.

Secondly, What If I want to show data from specific date to another date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options here:

- You keep using a `LineChart` and add custom labels while disabling the regular ones:

  renderer.setXLabels(0);
  renderer.addXTextLabel(date.getTime(), "Label");
- You use a `TimeChart` which is a `LineChart` displaying time values using a format provided by you, instead of the `LineChart`.

Comment: can you explain the formate please, I need dates however i saw an example of Hours and minutes. But can't make it to work for days

Comment: Look at the SimpleDateFormat class for understanding the format.

Comment: kindly review the question again now Thanks for the help earlier.

Answer (score 1):

umar.
Check my following code. I use a `TimeChart` here.

```
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);
    // mDateFrom and mDateTo are Date Objects
        // Set the date span here
    setChartSettings(renderer, "title", "x_tiele", "y_title", 
            mDateFrom.getTime(),
            mDateTo.getTime(), 0, 1, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildDateDataset(titles, mHashMapGroupedEntites);

    return ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(context, dataset,
                renderer, "yyyy/MM/dd HH"+":00:00");
```

Try this.

```
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(diaSeries);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mrenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    mrenderer.setXAxisMin(YOUR_DATE_MIN);
    mrenderer.setXAxisMax(YOUR_DATE_MAX);

    // XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mrenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    mrenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
    mrenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    // mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

    graphLayout.addView(ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset, mrenderer, "MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try this

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(diaSeries);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mrenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.DIAMOND);
        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
        mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

        graphLayout.addView(ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset, mrenderer, "MM/dd/yyyy"));